# How to change RAID 1 to RAID 0 on a server

Tags: server, partitioning, raid, mdadm

I have bought a dedicated server from OVH and it has two disks, but I can only use one disk since (seems like) the other one is to mirror the data of the first. I have searched tutorials on how to make it so I can use both drives to store data but these works with physical devices and the others only works without accessing the user that uses the disks. But with OVH my only options are login to an account with sudo privileges and to log in rescue mode.

Is there a way to change the disk from RAID 1 to RAID 0?

I don't have any data and I have command line access.

Comment: You should be able to reorganize the disks using a combination of `mdadm`, `vmdiskscan`, `lvscan`, and `vgchange` commands. But exactly which commands, which parameters, and in which order depends heavily on your current installation and IMHO is beyond this Q&A site. I managed to revive a broken NAS this way once.

Comment: A RAID 0 stripes the data across both drives and once data is written to the first drive you cannot create a RAID 0 without wiping out all the data on the first drive since it will create a whole new partition table scheme.  Back up your data first before messing with the RAID, or pull one of the drives since they are a mirror and add in a new drive, create your RAID 0, then copy all the data off the other drive back to the new array.

Comment: Just to note that with a RAID 0 there is no redundancy.  If either drive dies all the data will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was that I wasn't seeing the option to change the RAID when customizing the partition configuration. [image: Customize the partition configuration]

When entering to the config option and selecting the second disk it allows you to change from RAID 1 to RAID 0 with all the warnings included.